# Undo git commit amend and keep changes in index

Tags: git

I resolved huge merge-conflict after rebase and mistakenly runned `git commit --amend` instead of `git commit`.
Now git thinks that previous commit has all my changes. 
Is there a way to undo `git commit --amend` and get in index all my changes after merging?

Comment: Why don't you run `git commit --amend -m "text"` once again to fix the message?

Comment: @harunyardimci Because he did not only amend the commit's message but also its content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with taking a copy of you repo in case I've written anything wrong in my instructions.

You've amended your commit so the original un-amended commit is still somewhere in the tree although no branch points at it.

You can probably find it back using one of the following:

```
git fsck --lost-found
git reflog
```

Then you can reset back to this commit. Reseting *soft* will only make you point at that commit and will leave your files unchanged, reseting *hard* will wipe all changes (and the merge conflicts you were resolving):

```
git reset [--hard|--soft] <your_commit_hash>
```

Comment: `git reflog` and `git reset --soft %mychangehash%` returned my changes to index. Thanks a lot! You saved something about 4 hours for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

do git revert 
for further assistance checkout: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert